# Discussing Torah with non-Jews

Tags: discussion

I'm a gentile who accepts Judaism as reality, and I find this site informative and interesting. But I just read in another post on this site that there are aspects of Torah that non-Jews aren't meant to learn. I don't know how that works in practice... I'll ask a rabbi but also curious about how it works on Mi Yodeya.

What is it that gentiles are or are not allowed to read, elsewhere and here? How about actually asking and discussing questions about halacha or rabbinic texts (including the Talmud or even Kabbalah), not for the sake of mimicking Jewish practice but instead for better understanding it?

Comment: AFAIK Mi Yodeya has no policy about who can ask questions, as long as they're on topic etc.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7260/2

Comment: There are two questions here: one about what gentiles are allowed to read in general, and one about site policy. To the extent that the former can be distinguished from [this one](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7260/2), I recommend that you post a new question on [Judaism.SE]. To the extent that the latter can be distinguished from [this one](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/42/publicly-teaching-halachah), I recommend that you specify how here, on this Meta question, possibly after your other question (should you post it) is answered.

Comment: Thanks! I've written a question to you in a comment here http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/42/publicly-teaching-halachah/761#comment4051_761, and made a new question on the main site http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23042/non-jews-learning-or-being-taught-torah.

Answer (score 7):

Mi Yodeya has no policy regarding this for several reasons.

- It's not a Jewish-only site. Its founder and moderators are Jews, and most of its users are, but that's as far as it goes.
- There is no possible verification for, or enforcement of, any such rule. This is the internet, after all.
- Such a policy, if it were to exist at all, would have to be based on a Rabbi's ruling, and that's something that individual users would have to obtain from *their* Rabbi.

This explains why there is no official Mi Yodeya policy. So, the question

> What is it that gentiles are or are not allowed to read, elsewhere and here?

is really a main-site question (such as you've already asked). I don't think it can be answered in a real "Meta" way, i.e., vis-à-vis site policy, since even if the site were to try to institute some policy regarding this, despite the fact that it would be useless, different rabbis would probably have different rulings, making any such policy impossible to formulate properly.

The best advice would be to ask a Rabbi who can understand your exact circumstances and give you a personalized ruling.

Comment: Also, I wonder if SE would be OK with such an exclusive site on their platform.

Comment: @DoubleAA I had that in mind for number one. Not that it matters since, on the internet, no one knows that you're a dog, lhavdil.

Comment: [Woof!](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/773/will-there-ever-be-a-meet-up#comment1679_773)

Comment: @DoubleAA Follow the Yellow Link Road?

Comment: ...because of the wonderful things I do. ;)